# AWS EventBridge Pipes: Is it possible to apply enrichment input transformer on an array of events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I'm evaluating EventBridge Pipes and I have the following setup:

| Source | Filtering | Enrichment | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kinesis stream → | Not configured → | Step Functions → | SNS Topic |

Additionally the batch size for the kinesis stream is set > 1. In this szenario this does mean, that the Step Function retrieves an array of kinesis events.

The enrichment input transformer works fine as long as I provide a single event:

##### **`event:`**

```json
{
    "kinesisSchemaVersion": "1.0",
    "partitionKey": "1",
    "sequenceNumber": "49590338271490256608559692538361571095921575989136588898",
    "data": "SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0Lg==",
    "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1545084650.987,
    "eventSource": "aws:kinesis",
    "eventVersion": "1.0",
    "eventID": "shardId-000000000006:49590338271490256608559692538361571095921575989136588898",
    "eventName": "aws:kinesis:record",
    "invokeIdentityArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/lambda-role",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
    "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-2:123456789012:stream/lambda-stream"
  }
```

##### **`transformer:`**

```json
{
  "data": <$.data>
}
```

##### **`output:`**

```json
{
  "data": "Hello, this is a test."
}
```

The desired behaviour is to get base64 decoded data payload, which works fine. However if I provide an array of events this transformer is not correct anymore and provides empty value.

```json
[{
    ...
    "data": "SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0Lg==",
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    "data": "SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0Lg==",
    ...
  }
]
```

One possible transformer I figured out looks like this:

```json
{
  "data": <$.0.data>
}
```

The problem here is I am getting only the decoded payload for the first element.
My goal is, of course, to get the decoded payload for each event in the array.

Do You have any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but _if_ they're using JSONPath you should be able to do something like `$.data[:]` ... when I was playing around with it, I decided it was just better to write a Lambda to process the entire event.

Comment: Thx, but unfortunately JSONPath isin't working with the arrays here...